# List of connections of a NIC card in C#

Tags: c#, ip-address, connection, arp, nic

I have two network interface cards installed in my system, I want the list of all the computers that are connected to a particular NIC card or I need a code that will work similar to "arp -a" command in DOS. I need a C# code to do this. Please help me.

Comment: I think you would have to write a C-Interface to access the hardware information. Unless you can read pings.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the output from `arp -a` then this is simple :

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "arp.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a";
p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();

MessageBox.Show(output);  //etc... parse this for what you need
```

You will of course need to add :

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```